# How do I draw a semi transparent line on a html canvas element without dots in the line?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

Ok so I am working on a drawing application and I would like to make it so the user can change the opacity of their brush. I have gotten the opacity to change by changing the alpha value, but when I draw a line with the lowered alpha value, the line has many dots of different transparency in it. How can I make the semi transparent line draw very clean with occasional transparency changes only at overlaps?

Image 1 is what happens when I run my code

Image 2 is what I would like to achieve if possible
[image: This is what happens when I run my code]
[image: This is what I would like to achieve]

Here is my javascript code for my canvas

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    //Resizing
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    //Variables
    let painting = false;

    function startPosition(e) {
        painting = true;
        draw(e);
    }

    function finishedPosition() {
        painting = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }

    function draw(e) {
        if(!painting) return;

        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";

        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);

    }

    //EventListeners
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);

});
```

Comment: For single color, store all coords, clear the whole canvas and redraw as a single sub-path. For different colors draw once opaque on an offscreen canvas* then lower the globalAlpha of the visible canvas and drawImage the offscreen canvas. (* if you really just have these drawings you could use compositing to make it all on the same canvas.

Comment: ah ok, i found some code for it but i don't really understand what's actually happening that welll. are there any resources where i can read more on this?

Comment: You can try to keep the drawing opacity at 100% and change the canvas opacity using CSS. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend refractoring your `draw()` and doing some OOP with canvas ([shameless plug of my canvas credibility](https://passtow.com/)).

I say OOP so that you can track the users previous coordinates and current coordinates in a much cleaner state.

Once some OOP is put in place, you can take advantage of the following code:

```
function draw(e) {
    //Update Current coords
    this.currX = e.clientX
    this.currY = e.clientY

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.prevX, this.prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(this.currX, this.currY);
    ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;          //10
    ctx.lineCap = this.lineCap;              //round
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.lineColor;        //blue 
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    // Update coords
    this.prevX = this.currX
    this.prevY = this.currY
}
```